# Remove leading zeros from abbreviated date with PHP

Tags: php, date, zero

I was wondering if there is a way, using PHP, to change this date format: 01.08.86 (January 8, 1986) to this format: 1.8.86.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<?php

$date = "01.08.86";
$unix = strtotime($date);
echo date('n.j.y', $unix);
```

Comment: All I really needed was n.j.y  Thanks alot Sean!

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex based solution:

```
$str = '01.08.86';
$a = array('/^0(\d+)/','/\.0(\d+)/');
$b = array('\1','.\1');
$str = preg_replace($a,$b,$str);

// $str is now '1.8.86'
```