# Date format from 26.09.2011 to 26.9.2011

Tags: php, date, format, digits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove leading zeros from abbreviated date with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480112/remove-leading-zeros-from-abbreviated-date-with-php)

I have a problem formating date from 26.09.2011 to 26.9.2011.

Of course if there is two digits month there should be two digits (26.12.2011).

I am looking for answer all over web. Could anyone tell me how to acomplish that.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date("j.n.Y");
```

will print current date in the format you specified.

Comment: `j, n, Y` would output "26, 9, 2011" and the question needs the output to be "26.9.2011" which should be `j.n.Y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('26.09.2011');
echo $date->format('d.n.Y');
```

`m` prints two digits month, `n` prints month without leading zeros.

Comment: While you're answer would provide exactly what's asked, it's worth pointing out that "d" prints out the day with a leading zero if it's less than 10.  As you pointed out with m/n, the equivalent of "d" without a leading zero is "j".